# Android menu items are not coloured as defined

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have declared my toolbar menu like this. The icons for the menu items are vector assets, but the colors which are defined for the items are not set correctly. Only the color for the sort button is correct, the search button and the settings button are not correct. They appear in gray (see screenshot for example). Is this the right way to declare colour for buttons or did i do something wrong. :-P

### menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/miSearch"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/miSort"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_SortBy">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/miSettings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_Settings">
</item>
</menu>
```

### ic_add.xml (The other buttons are declared similar.)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/colorActionBar"
    android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

### colors.xml

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="colorActionBar">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

[Screenshot of the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIiM2.png)

Answer (score 0):

To change the color in the menu bar, add the following line to your theme:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/custom_color</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme file you have to put this :

```
 <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/text_color</item>
</style>
```